# Desconocer de algo

Tags: verbos, preposiciones

I just read the following [article](https://actualidad.rt.com/viral/390537-encuentran-botella-mensaje-arrojada-mas-30-anos) and I can't figure out what they mean by **desconocer de** in the last sentence:

> En aquel entonces, la pareja decidió enviar un mensaje dentro de una botella al río desde una orilla cerca a su casa tras **desconocer de** un hallazgo similar.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is not fully idiomatic in my opinion but the meaning of desconocer is pretty clear: to do not know.

According to the DLE:

> **[desconocer](https://dle.rae.es/desconocer)**
> 2. tr. No conocer.

I've not read the article but the sentence provided means that the couple decided to send the bottle because they have found something amazing, something that they thought was **unheard-of**.

According to the Cambridge Dictionary:

> **[unheard-of](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/unheard-of)**
> surprising or shocking because **not known** about or previously experienced

Probably it's a case of poor translation because the object used with verb **desconocer** does not need the preposition **de** (which is present in the word unheard-**of**).

Being **unheard-of** their discovery, they decide to send a message in a bottle. Or, using the same order,

> They decided to send a message in a bottle **because** their discovery was **unheard-of**.

A more idiomatic version of the sentence would be:

> En aquel entonces, la pareja decidió enviar un mensaje dentro de una
> botella al río desde una orilla cerca **de** su casa **al** desconocer un
> hallazgo similar.

I've replaced the preposition **tras**. It doesn't mean **because** in Spanish which it's the word that the text seems to imply. Particle **al** plus infinitive does imply a causal sense in Spanish.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. The article's author probably meant to say "...tras *enterarse* de un hallazgo similar."

Answer (score 0):

Just the fact that it could be found didn't cross their minds. They were not aware of it at that time.

- Nunca supieron de ese hecho.
- Nunca se les pasó por la mente buscar, recibir eso.
- No estaban conscientes de que eso pudiera ser encontrado, por eso no lo buscaron hasta aquel momento.

Y por lo mismo pensaron después de eso ¿Por qué no? Enviar uno y ver que tal.